How to transfer each voxel in voxel model to be independent geometry
I'm a new user of Blender. I want to use Blender 4.2.3 to voxelize the fan STL model and export the voxel fan STL model, and each voxel in the voxel fan model is independent.  I use the “Modifier >> Remesh >> Blocks“ to generate the voxel model, but it's almost impossible to use “Loop cut“ or “Knife“ to cut it one by one to generate voxel.
Summary, I hope to know how to transfer each voxel in the voxel model to be independent geometry.





Note that the model is not comprised of individual blocks, it looks like it is but if you remove a vertex and look inside you'll see it is hollow. Given the complexity of the mesh I'd guess this would take a lot of time and maybe crash your PC. I don't know of a builtin way to do it, you may be able to piece a script together to do it but it would not be straightforward.

Question: does simply separating "faces" work or do you need cubes? Question 2: In case of cubes, do you need the invisible (inside) cubes to exist throughout the entire thickness or can they be just the surface cubes?

@Gorgious Thank you very much for your reply. I agree with your point, and I want to know the format of the model that can be imported to Blender as the mesh or entity.

@DanielMöller Thank you very much for your reply. A1: I need each voxel to be a cube rather than simply separating faces. A2:  The primary task of this work is to generate the voxel model with independent voxel, and the surface cubes or entire thickness cubes can be all acceptable.

I think what you want is to use a geometry nodes tree, distribute points in the volume formed by the mesh in a grid fashion, and then instance your cubes on each point of the grid. But beware, this will generate a ginormous amount of geometry.

@Gorgious I think your advice is very helpful. I use the Geometry nodes tree to transform geometry and the operational steps follow the Fig.4(in the question content).  The information on each voxel can be found in the interface of Blender.  However, when the "Realize Instance ”  node is added to the Geometry node tree,  voxels are merged to be an entity. Is there a way to "Realize Instance ”  and not merge the voxel.

When you use realize instances, they are joined into a single (mesh) object, but the vertices are not welded. You can separate your blocks into individual objects again, using the "Separate" operator / > by loose parts

@Leander Thanks a lot for your help, and the "Separate > by loose parts" can separate cubes. Unfortunately, another problem occurs when I want to export geometry. When I export geometry in STL format, cubes are merged to be an entity. Do  I need to operate some settings or export the cubes with another format.

That seems the case with blenders stl exporter. Since I don't know anything about STL, I can't tell, if this is an inherent STL limitation or an exporter problem. If your target application accepts other formats, I'd recommend obj / fbx / gltf for static files. There is also the "batch" option in the stl exporter. So if your target app accepts a batch of files, that would be an option.

@Leander Thank you very much. I have used Blender extension to realize batch export STL voxel model.
